# Why does my PSVR box not always turn on?

Tags: technical-issues, playstation-vr

When I first got my PSVR, turning on my PS4 would also turn on the PSVR box, which would allow the TV to display the output from the PS4, so this seems like the intended behavior.

However, sometimes, the box does not turn on (e.g. the light stays red instead of turning white). Even if I'm not trying to use the VR, this prevents the TV from getting the PS4's output, as there is an HDMI cable going *from* the PS4 *to* the box and then another going *from* the box and *to* the TV.

I've been able to fix the issue by wiggling the HDMI cable from the PS4 in and out of the box (read: unplugging it and plugging it back in), but this kind of defeats the purpose of letting me lazily turn on my PS4 from the couch, since I have to get up and mess with the cables.

Is this a known issue and are there any solutions?

Comment: Just to be sure: Is it the normal PS4 or the PS4 Pro you are using?

Comment: @mbee the regular PS4